# Use of two Likert scale for correlations

Tags: spss

I am struggling with two questionnaires. One comprises of 61 items explaining several components of emotional intelligence with 6 point scale while on the other hand 10 items making empathetic listening with 7 point scale. Can I correlate the factors obtained from these two questionnaires? If any scale modification is required,how to proceed the same using SPSS?

Comment: No objective distance metric exists for Likert scales, so a pure correlation (Pearson) does not make sense.

Comment: @NickSabbe In order for the individual items to be added, or scaled and added - as the OP has already done to obtain the factors - the items have *already been assumed* to be interval-scaled. I see no issue with then computing correlations with the resulting quantities; no additional assumption would be needed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can correlate the two factors; factors are (attempts to) derive the latent variables that are inherent in the answers to questions (in this case, your Likert items). Once you have these latent factors, they can be treated as interval level.

A different question is the proper way to do the factor analysis on Likert items. Since Likert items themselves are somewhere between ordinal and interval, some people say to not use Pearson correlations to do this.